# how to delete particular json object from array of array

Tags: arrays, angular7

I have `array within the array` and i want to delete particular JSON object by its value.

```
rows=[
[isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'false',name:'Abc',data:'ABC',Value:'ABC']
[isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'false',name:'Abc1',data:'ABC1',Value:'ABC1']
[isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'true',name:'Abc2',data:'ABC2',Value:'ABC2']
[isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'true',name:'Abc3',data:'ABC3',Value:'ABC3']
]
```

I want

```
rows=[
[name:'Abc',data:'ABC',Value:'ABC']
[name:'Abc1',data:'ABC1',Value:'ABC1']
[name:'Abc2',data:'ABC2',Value:'ABC2']
[name:'Abc3',data:'ABC3',Value:'ABC3']
]
```

I want to remove all the data which has boolean values present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you have provided has array of objects (not array of array) and should the have following syntax -

```
rows=[
    {isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'false',name:'Abc',data:'ABC',Value:'ABC'},
    {isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'false',name:'Abc1',data:'ABC1',Value:'ABC1'},
    {isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'true',name:'Abc2',data:'ABC2',Value:'ABC2'},
    {isTrue:'false',isAvailable:'true',name:'Abc3',data:'ABC3',Value:'ABC3'}
]
```

So, you want to delete the key-value pairs from a JSON object which you can do using -

```js
for (var row of rows) {    
  delete row['isTrue'];  // this will delete the isTrue key from the object
  delete row['isAvailable'];  // this will delete the isAvailable key from the object
}
```

You can check the following link for other ways of deleting a key:
[Remove a key from a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I want to delete isTrue and isAvailable both

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please accept the answer if it works or share further details if required.